# How can i change components data in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new in Vue.js. i don't know how can i render four message like this

```
hi
bye

go
back
```

my result is render go, back. i think my code is not render hello1.vue component.
i want render hello, hello1 components. how can i fix it?

#### hello.vue

```
<template>
  <P> {{ hello.a }} </p>
  <p> {{ hello.b }} </p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
       return{
          hello:{
            a = "hi",
            b = "bye"
       }
    },
    props: ['hello1']
}
</script>
```

#### hello2.vue

```
<template>
  <hello-vue :hello="hello1" />
</template>

<script>
import helloVue from './hello.vue'
export default {
    data(){
       return{
          hello1:{
            a = "go",
            b = "back"
       }
    },
    components:{
       'hello-vue': helloVue
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the data in a bit of a messy way. So first thing is we need to split this into a parent and child component. The child component will print out your two lines, while parent component will call and pass data.

Secondly in `Hello.vue` you have `props` AND `data`, the template is only accessing `hello` and not `hello1` meaning the props variable isnt parsed.

Thirdly `<template>` may have only 1 child so that will cause rendering issues as well.

There are different ways, but let's try this

`HelloItem.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <P> {{ hello.a }} </p>
    <p> {{ hello.b }} </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
       return { }
    },
    props: ['hello']
}
</script>
```

And now we call this twice by passing in data
`HelloView.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <hello-item :hello="hello1"/>
    <hello-item :hello="hello2"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloItem from './HelloItem.vue'
export default {
    data() {
       return {
          hello1:{
            a: "hi",
            b: "bye"
          },
          hello2:{
            a: "go",
            b: "back"
          },
       }
    },
    components:{
       'hello-item': HelloItem
    }
}
</script>
```

Let me know if this answers your question.